# How to remove remove self-intersections(?) from a river network line

Tags: line, vector, network, self-intersection, dangle

I am working with a new global-scale river network that splits around large islands (blue lines).

I will be working with the river network in Google Earth Engine and have completed some prior vector processing in GIS (e.g. simplifying the line to reduce the number of vertices, splitting into smaller parts of the network, etc).

However, I am having trouble with some self-intersecting(?) parts of the network as shown in the images below (problem shown in red where the 3 line segments meet). I am not sure if this is a "self-intersection" problem or something else.

Is it possible to find and remove these self-intersecting(?) parts of the network?  The network is very large, so not feasible to visually check and remove.

In QGIS, I ran topology checker, but the case is not flagged as a dangle.  I have also been unable to repair with v.clean or repair geometry.

Is there another approach to find the problematic parts of the river network (i.e., to remove the self-intersecting parts)?

[image: Mult-directional river network]
Multi-direction river network

[image: Problematic line that self-intersects]
Problematic line (red) that self-intersects(?)

[image]
Problematic part of line (red)

Comment: It's trivial to *detect* backwards spikes (A-B B-C angle is ~0 or ~360). What do you want to do about it?  Remove vertex B?

Comment: @Vince - yes, ideally to remove instances of vertex B, but to keep the remainder of the line.

Comment: So, retrieve the geometry, generate an empty list, walk the vertices from 0 to N-2, compute atan2(y[n+1]-y[n],x[n+1]-x[n]), and bearing for seg[n] to seg[n+1], and for any point not within your *uh-oh* threshold, add vertex n for the accumulator list, then generate a new line without the bad apples. Lots of room for optimizing there, but it's a place to start.